# Fiware Keyrock as RAAS - Registration as a service

Tags: fiware

Can I use Keyrock for registration as a service without SSO button on my site ? 
For example as they have https://auth0.com .

I've seen some documenations with apiary , for example how to create user 
http://docs.keyrock.apiary.io/#reference/scim-2.0/users/create-a-user
but there is no docs how to connect fiware from code before i make request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCIM API is a REST API that you can use sending normal HTTP requests. But you have to take into account that there is an API opened only for administrators.

So in the FIWARE Lab public instance you cannot use it. However, if you have your own installation you will be able to use the API.

BR